# Use js libraries with Laravel and webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, leaflet

I would like to know how can I use a leaflet plugin with Laravel and webpack.

Currently, I have :

webpack.mix.js :

```
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/main.js',

], 'public/js/app.js');
```

app.js :

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

bootstrap.js :

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default; // default is very important.

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

main.js :

```
let leaflet = require('./leaflet.js');
let GroupLayer = require('./grouplayer-leaflet.js');
let antPath = require('./leaflet-ant-path.js');

$(window).on('load', function() {
... my code
```

In  ./resources/assets/js/ I have the differents files

- app.js
- main.js
- bootstrap.js
- leaflet.js
- grouplayer-leaflet.js
- leaflet-ant-path.js

But I have an error :

> ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/leaflet-ant-path.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'leaflet'

Comment: The `./` prefix means `require()` is looking in the current directory for a JS file with that name. Drop the prefix (as per the first line of your bootstrap.js: `require('lodash')`) to specify a library.

Comment: I have 3 files : leaflet.js, grouplayer-leaflet.js and leaflet-ant-path.js

Comment: try `import * as antPath from 'leaflet-ant-path'`

Comment: Can you show the contents of `leaflet-ant-path.js`?

Comment: sure @RossWilson : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubenspgcavalcante/leaflet-ant-path-bower/master/dist/leaflet-ant-path.js

Comment: You have `require('leaflet')` in that file that should be `require('./leaflet')`